# Floating point equivalence?

Tags: .net, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I want to be able to compare two doubles disregarding a possible precision loss. Is there a method already that handles this case?

If not, is there a threshold/guideline to know how much is an adequate equivalence between two doubles?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The threshold is completely dependent to the problem itself. For some problems, you might consider 1.001 equal to 1.002 and for some problems, you might need a much smaller threshold.

The general techique is:

```
Math.Abs(a - b) < some_epsilon    // `a` is roughly equivalent to `b`
```

Comment: This is good, but picking a reasonable value for some_epsilon is tricky.

Comment: Indeed it's tricky; and no general recommendation works. Personally, I've experienced its trickiness in ACM/ICPC geometry questions and those that require binary searching the solution space.

Answer (score 3):

A very good, thorough option for this is:

```
public static bool DoubleEquality(double a, double b) 
{
    const double epsilonValue = 1e-15;
    if (double.IsNaN(a))
        return double.IsNaN(b);
    else if (double.IsInfinity(a))
        return double.IsInfinity(b);
    else if (a == 0) 
        return b == 0;
    else
        return Math.Abs(a - b) <= Math.Abs(a * epsilonValue);
}
```

Note that Double.Epsilon is NOT a good epsilon value for this.  This creates an epsilon that scales somewhat with the magnitude of your first value, which helps quite a bit.

Comment: +1, but perhaps worth noting the difference in your function to standard equality (NaN != NaN)

Comment: oh and do you want Positive and Negative infinity to be considered equal?

Comment: Yeah - it's easy to add some extra checks, depending on your conditions.  I've also taken out the 0 check at times, although that requires changing the last line slightly.  (Currently, 0!=1e-20, which you may want to be equal).